# How do I remove file and parameter name from URL but keep parameter value?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this url:

`https://website.com/pages/page.php?id=23`

And I want to turn it into:

`https://website.com/pages/23`

I have tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pages/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Which works. But I have files under this `/pages` folder that needs to be treated as regular pages. For example:

`https://website.com/pages/login.php`

But this gets treated as the ID and tries to redirect to:

`https://website.com/pages/page.php?id=login`

I have tried to change the `^(.*)$` to `^([0-9]+)$` but it does not work.

In my root folder I have another .htaccess file that removes the .php extension from all files. Is it bad practice to have two separate .htaccess files? If so, how do I combine them?

That .htaccess file looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

RewriteEngine  on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

So my questions are:

- How do I change my code to only allow IDs after "/pages/" to be rewritten to a new URL?
- How do I combine my two .htaccess files into one and where do I place it?

Comment: If the `/pages/login.php` is existent file meaning that it exists in your `/pages` folder then your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should exlude it completely from the rule and no rewriting should happen for files that exist in /pages .

Comment: But ```/pages/page.php``` exist also? How do I single out this file in that case?

Comment: @starkeen If I got to ```/pages/login.php``` it works at expected, but since I have removed .php from my root .htaccess I want to be able to go to ```/pages/login``` without it being rewritten as ```/pages/page.php?id=login```

Comment: You need to add a rule to remove .php extension  in your `/pages` htaccess otherwise you wont be able to access `login` without .php extension.  Your parent htaccess rules apply to the root and not to the `/pages` folder since this folder has its own htaccess file.

Comment: @starkeen Aahh, now I understand. I thought the root .htaccess file set rules for all subfolders aswell. That solved it! Cheers!